# Integrating EgoImageLoader by using UIImageView instead of egoimageview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios7, egoimageview

I'm new to objective c. Want to implement EGOIMAGELOADER for my customised tableview, but as i have mutliple uiimageview and that has to be in their respective fix position so i have created uitablecell in xib and placed the uiimageview in the alignment i want it.

I went through the ego example but there the egoimageview is being used to create imageview dynamically.

I want to use my uiimageview with egoimageloader and not use egoimageview as i have fixed placement of imageviews in uitablecell.

I want to implement lazyloading and caching of images using egoimageview.

Can anyone help me with example or sample code to achieve above requirement.

As i'm using normal code for loading images in uiimageview for tablecell. So don't know what to include for code snippet.